# Excel If formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am trying to run a simple formula in Excel:

```
=IF(V3>419, "Pass", IF(V3>459, "Merit", IF(V3>499, "Dist", IF(V3>519, "Dist*","Fail"))))
```

I have 2 columns; Overall and Grade

```
Overall     Grade
70          Fail
220         Fail
420         Pass
```

There must be a simpler way?

Comment: So you're asking for a way to do this, without as many statements?

Comment: maybe or just to fix that so that it works... am i missing a comma, or "" somewhere?

Comment: it only seems to work for pass at present?

Comment: Might want to add a bit of detail to your question, it wasn't clear what you were asking.

Answer (score 2):

So based on your comments you want to know why this formula isn't working, and then secondly if it can be streamlined?

It doesn't work because everything that counts as a Merit, Dist or Dist* is higher than 419, and therefore counts as a Pass.

Your formula evaluates from left to right, so before it does anything else it checks to see if the score is higher than 419. Even if the score is 800 it's higher than 419 and so the first test is TRUE. Excel doesn't think it needs to keep going, so it stops there, calling it a Pass.

If you select the cell with your formula in it and go to the Formulas tab, and select Evaluate Formula under Formula Auditing, you can step through the formula to see exactly what's happening.

There are two ways to fix this. One way is to replace the current statemtns with an AND statement

```
AND(V3>419,V3<459)
```

But this is clunky. You're better off simply reversing the statements:

```
=IF(V3>519,"Dist*",IF(V3>499,"Dist",IF(V3>459,"Merit",IF(V3>419,"Pass","Fail"))))
```

This way if it's not high enough for a Dist* it will check for the next highest and so on.

---

Sadly, for part two, I can't think of a way of streamlining the formula without overcomplicating the solution.

Comment: For part two, I would personally suggest using a table with the values and corresponding results, with a `VLOOKUP`.

Comment: It's a pretty good way to go; though it would make the formula more complicated, which would go against the question, it would be more future-safe as you could adjust the targets in the table rather than having to adjust the formula.

Answer (score 1):

You're working backwards, you need the highest grade first, otherwise a 1,000 will pass on the first `if` for "pass" rather than make it to "dist*". Like this:

`=IF(V3>519,"Dist*",IF(V3>499,"Dist",IF(V3>459,"Merit",IF(V3>419,"Pass","Fail"))))`

Otherwise, you'll need to nest your `if` between values, which is much less clean e.g. `=if(419<v3<459,"pass",...`

Comment: Ah, beat me to it! :D